# MATLAB changing variable inside a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I created the Matlab code below to implement the value of an European Put following the implementation inside [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjI2u7_6MvaAhWsxYMKHRjsAw0QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpersonal.strath.ac.uk%2Fd.j.higham%2FPlist%2FP46.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2zBaQvmpsd5pAW7__fQZYC). I am trying to graph the value of M against the value of the European Put as M increases from 20 to 250 in time steps of 5.

In order to do this, I created a for loop to change the value of M,

```
for M = 20:5:250
```

I think that I need to create this for loop in order to change the value of M. Unit testing shows that I did something wrong. The for loop isn't working as intended. The graph produced by the code is referencing the original value of M (defined to be 200) instead of the changing values of M inside the for loop. I don't know why the code returns the original value of M instead of the values inside the for loop.

```
clear all;
close all;
% EURO9  Binomial method for a European put.
%
% Uses explicit solution based on binomial expansion.
% Vectorized, based on logs to avoid overflow,
% and avoids computing with zeros.
%%%%%%%%%% Problem and method parameters %%%%%%%%%%%%%
S = 9 ;E = 10 ;T = 3 ;r = 0.06 ;sigma = 0.3 ; M = 200;
dt = T/M ; A = 0.5*(exp(-r*dt)+exp((r+sigma^2)*dt)) ;
u= A + sqrt(A^2-1) ; d = 1/u ; p = (exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d) ;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% cut-off index

for M = 20:5:250
    z = max(1,min(M+1,floor( log((E*u)/(S*d^(M+1)))/(log(u/d)) )));
    % Option values at time T
    W=E-S*d.^([M:-1:M-z+1]').*u.^([0:z-1]');
    % log/cumsum version using cut-off index z
    tmp1 = cumsum(log([1;[M:-1:M-z+2]'])) - cumsum(log([1;[1:z-1]']));
    tmp2 = tmp1 + log(p)*([0:z-1]') + log(1-p)*([M:-1:M-z+1]');
    value = exp(-r*T)*sum(exp(tmp2).*W);
    disp('M is'), disp(M)
    disp('Option value is'), disp(value)
    hold on;
    xlabel('M') % x-axis label
    ylabel('European Put') % y-axis label
    plot(M,value,'r*')
end
```

Unit testing shows that my code is wrong. Testing against M=20 returns a value less than one when the true value is 1.5076.

Did I write the for loop completely wrong? Why is it referencing the value of M=200 at every iteration instead of the increment specified in the for loop for M = 20:5:250?

As an example, running

```
clear all;
close all;
% EURO9  Binomial method for a European put.
%
% Uses explicit solution based on binomial expansion.
% Vectorized, based on logs to avoid overflow,
% and avoids computing with zeros.
%%%%%%%%%% Problem and method parameters %%%%%%%%%%%%%
S = 9 ;E = 10 ;T = 3 ;r = 0.06 ;sigma = 0.3 ; M = 20;
dt = T/M ; A = 0.5*(exp(-r*dt)+exp((r+sigma^2)*dt)) ;
u= A + sqrt(A^2-1) ; d = 1/u ; p = (exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d) ;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% cut-off index


z = max(1,min(M+1,floor( log((E*u)/(S*d^(M+1)))/(log(u/d)) )));
% Option values at time T
W=E-S*d.^([M:-1:M-z+1]').*u.^([0:z-1]');
% log/cumsum version using cut-off index z
tmp1 = cumsum(log([1;[M:-1:M-z+2]'])) - cumsum(log([1;[1:z-1]']));
tmp2 = tmp1 + log(p)*([0:z-1]') + log(1-p)*([M:-1:M-z+1]');
value = exp(-r*T)*sum(exp(tmp2).*W);
disp('M is'), disp(M)
disp('Option value is'), disp(value)
```

returns

```
Option value is
    1.5076
```

and running

```
clear all;
close all;
% EURO9  Binomial method for a European put.
%
% Uses explicit solution based on binomial expansion.
% Vectorized, based on logs to avoid overflow,
% and avoids computing with zeros.
%%%%%%%%%% Problem and method parameters %%%%%%%%%%%%%
S = 9 ;E = 10 ;T = 3 ;r = 0.06 ;sigma = 0.3 ; M = 25;
dt = T/M ; A = 0.5*(exp(-r*dt)+exp((r+sigma^2)*dt)) ;
u= A + sqrt(A^2-1) ; d = 1/u ; p = (exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d) ;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% cut-off index


z = max(1,min(M+1,floor( log((E*u)/(S*d^(M+1)))/(log(u/d)) )));
% Option values at time T
W=E-S*d.^([M:-1:M-z+1]').*u.^([0:z-1]');
% log/cumsum version using cut-off index z
tmp1 = cumsum(log([1;[M:-1:M-z+2]'])) - cumsum(log([1;[1:z-1]']));
tmp2 = tmp1 + log(p)*([0:z-1]') + log(1-p)*([M:-1:M-z+1]');
value = exp(-r*T)*sum(exp(tmp2).*W);
disp('M is'), disp(M)
disp('Option value is'), disp(value)
```

returns

```
Option value is
    1.4666
```

Although, I don't get these values in the graph of the for loop for M = 20:5:250. I must have made a mistake inside the for loop.

Comment: I added two unit tests. Please let me know if I should add more information.

Comment: Is there a way to write M without initializing it? If I delete the original value of M=200 then I cannot run the program. I think that I need to initialize M and then override it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with `M`. You initialised `M=200` before the start of the loop which is affecting all the calculations that you're doing before the loop. Whereas in the two unit tests that you have provided, you used `M=20` and `M=25` for all the calculations respectively.

So the fix is to simply move the calculations that are affected by `M` inside the loop. i.e

```
S=9;   E=10;   T=3;   r=0.06;  sigma=0.3; 

for M = 20:5:250
    dt = T/M; 
    A = 0.5*(exp(-r*dt)+exp((r+sigma^2)*dt)) ;
    u = A + sqrt(A^2-1); 
    d = 1/u; 
    p = (exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d);

    %And here goes what you already have in your loop
    %....
    %....
end
```